# Hide build info from Actuator Info Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, spring-boot-actuator

Currently, I'm getting build info and build info from the Actuator/info endpoint. Like

```
{
    "git": {
        "commit": {
            "time": "2021-09-01T05:56:49Z",
            "id": "XXXXXX"
        },
        "branch": "task/XXXX-1234-adding-actuator-endpoint"
    },
    "build": {
        "version": "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
        "artifact": "XXXXX-XXXX",
        "name": "XXXX---XXXX",
        "group": "no.XXX.XXX",
        "time": "2021-09-01T07:18:23.786Z"
    }
}
```

What I need to do is hide build info from this, is that possible with the Gradle actuator for spring-boot? I only need to get git info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json line 249,
It should be as simple as `management.info.build.enabled=false` in your `application.properties`.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.info.auto-configured-info-contributors you can also keep the endpoint but not display all the default information (git and build) if you want some custom data.